# MySQL Error 1442 with two triggers and a stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, recursion, triggers, mysql-error-1442

I have read alot of articles about this error and doesn't seeme to find a solution to my problem.

As much as I understand, there is no infinite loop or recursive trigger calling in my code. But I still keep getting this error(1442). I've read a lot about how triggers act and how easy it is to make a recursive trigger system by accident but I do not understand where the mistake is. Also people have mistakenly used INSERT/UPDATE on the same row that launches the trigger, in my case it is not that way.

How can I solve this problem? If you have any specifying questions be sure to ask me. I'm really struggeling and need help - looking forward to replies

Here are my triggers and procedure:
(Just mentioning that I do not use any DELIMITERs because I use a MySQL Workbench and it's not necessary to use DELIMITERs there)

1)Trigger:

```
BEFORE INSERT ON `dim_content` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO sequence (increment) VALUE (new.sys_increment);
END
```

2)Trigger:

```
BEFORE INSERT ON `sequence` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE z INT(15);
    DECLARE w VARCHAR(10);
    SET z = NEW.increment;
    CALL alpha_numeric(z, w);
    UPDATE dim_content SET content_id = w WHERE sys_increment = z;
END
```

3)Procedure alpha_numeric():

```
PROCEDURE `alpha_numeric`(INOUT x INT(7), OUT y VARCHAR(10))
BEGIN
    DECLARE y CHAR(7);
    WHILE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sequence WHERE increment = x) DO
    SET x = x+1;
    END WHILE;
    IF (x < 9999) THEN
    BEGIN
    SET y = CONCAT('A', convert(x, CHAR(4)));
    END;
    /* There are more elif statements but that's not point of the problem */
END;
```

The practicable order of my logic is following:

INSERT INTO dim_content -> trigger BEFORE INSERT on dim_content -> INSERT INTO sequence -> trigger BEFORE INSERT on sequence -> CALL alpha_numeric() -> trigger BEFORE INSERT on sequence (continues) -> UPDATE dim_content

Comment: What is the full error message?

Comment: ERROR 1442: 1442: Can't update table 'dim_content' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

But I cannot understand it since at first I insert into the table and after that I update it and I do not have an update trigger that would make it recursive

Answer (score 0):

The error you get:

> ERROR 1442: 1442: Can't update table 'dim_content' in stored
>   function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked
>   this stored function/trigger.

The problem is with your second trigger:

```
BEFORE INSERT ON `sequence` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE z INT(15);
    DECLARE w VARCHAR(10);
    SET z = NEW.increment;
    CALL alpha_numeric(z, w);
    UPDATE dim_content SET content_id = w WHERE sys_increment = z;
END
```

The last statement updates the `dim_content` table.
But the second trigger is executed because you inserted a record in `dim_content` table.

This behavior is forbidden by MySQL, hence the error.

[The documentation says](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/faqs-triggers.html#faq-mysql-can-triggers-tables):

> Can triggers access tables?
>
> A trigger can access both old and new data in its own table. A trigger
>   can also affect other tables, ***but it is not permitted to modify a
>   table that is already being used (for reading or writing) by the
>   statement that invoked the function or trigger.***

Comment: Okay. That IS the root of the problem but how can i solve it? If I need to insert something to a table that has AI column made for it, but I need a database central AI. So I send it to a table called sequence that has all previous AI-s in it. Now a procedure needs to create an unique ID for me(as an OUT parameter) in a form that I need, so I send it back to the trigger that called the procedure. How can I insert/update it to the other table or even to the same table that triggered the procedure if I am not allowed to modify these tables?